# How to handle large http response data from observer in Angular application to avoid browser crash?

Tags: angular, http

Suppose we have a angular application which is using a data from api service using Http client. The data provide from the api is very large and we have to show all the data in the UI, but as the data is very large it leads to browser crash. How to handle this suitation.

I have tried pipe function resolve guard but web worker but not got proper solution.

Comment: What type of data do you have? Did you consider loading data in chunks?

Comment: The API should support retrieving the data in chunks. What is the size of the data you receive to make the browser crash?

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu what do you need to do to support that on client (Angular) side?

Comment: If your API will allow retrieving partial (do you implement the API?) you will just need to change your request (based on the API specification) like `https://localhost/data?from=0&to=50`. This may give you data from 0 to 50 (hypothetical because I don't know how your data looks) and you will be responsible to take them when you need.

Comment: @Aliaksei Maniuk - Database table rows having information about employees, the number of rows are millions.

Comment: @Andrew Radulescu, Thanks for your solutions, but what if there is no pagination is allowed.

Comment: @Hemant Gajbe you don't need to reflect the pagination in your app, just retrieve data in multiple pieces and display everything. Otherwise you will not be able to take it at all...